# Fairness issue in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

The following example shows an issue in the ScheduledExecutorService. I am scheduling two tasks "1" and "2" running longer than the schedule interval. Task "2" submits another task to execute only once.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestExecutorFairness {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final int interval = 200;
    final int sleeptime = 600;

    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors
        .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    // schedule task 1
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("1");
      }
    }, interval, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // schedule task 2
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("2");

        // submit task 3
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
            System.out.println("3");
          }
        });
      }
    }, interval, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

  }
}
```

The output I would expect is something like

```
1
2
1
2
3
```

But it is not executed that way. The task "3" is delayed very long but I need it to be executed ASAP.

Is there any way to change this behaviour to more fairness? Or has someone a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. It seems counterintuitive, because the JvaDoc of `ScheduledExecutorService` explicitly mentions

> Commands submitted using the Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) and ExecutorService submit methods are scheduled with a requested delay of zero

So one could assume that it should be feasible to submit commands like this. But in this case, there are some peculiarities. I can't point my finger at THE exact reason for this behavior, but it's obviously related to

- The tasks taking longer than the schedule interval
- The new task being submitted *from* an executed task
- The fact that the `ScheduledExecutorService` internally uses a `DelayedWorkQueue`
- Most importantly: That you are using a *single-threaded* ScheduledExecutorService

A considerable problem might also be that this is filling up the work queue and will sooner or later lead to an OutOfMemoryError. This can also be seen in this (slightly adjusted) example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestExecutorFairness {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final int interval = 200;
    final int sleeptime = 600;

    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = 
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // schedule task 1
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("1 at "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
      }
    }, interval, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    // schedule task 2
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(sleeptime);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("2 at "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));


        System.out.println("Submitting 3 to "+executor);
        // submit task 3
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              System.out.println("3 at "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
          }
        });
      }
    }, interval, interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

  }
}
```

The number of "queued tasks" in the Executor constantly increases.

A solution in this case is rather simple: Instead of a

`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`

you can just create a

`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3)`

Of course, this changes the "timing behavior" in this example. I have to assume that the `Thread.sleep()` in this example was solely intended to simulate a complex computation that did not fit into this example code. But maybe just making sure that the number of threads is at least `numberOfPeriodicTasks+1` can also be applied in your real application.

Comment: I also considered more threads but the `Thread.sleep()` is a placeholder for a Modbus TCP communication. The library for that is not designed for multithreading. I could also split into one executor for scheduling and one for executing, but that will fill up the queue of the executing one if tasks take too long.

Comment: So there are 2 periodic tasks that may take longer than the scheduling interval, and they are blocking the current thread - I can not imagine how it should be possible to execute a third task *immediately* in this case. The only solution that I see now, based on the current description, is to NOT *schedule* the Task3, but simply execute the respective `Runnable` directly in Task2 - but since this is just too obvious, I assume there is a reason why you did not do this...

Comment: I executed task 3 in task 2 just to simulate a later invocation. But I want to give direct submits a higher priority than scheduled tasks.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the source code of ScheduledExecutorService etc, and thought that it should be possible to replace the DelayedWorkQueue with a priority queue. But the infrastructure around that (wrapping all tasks into ScheduledFutureTasks internally, etc) makes this difficult. Depending on the exact requirements, one could consider creating an own ScheduledExecutorService implementation with the desired behavior, but this could be a considerable effort. Maybe someone finds a more simple and elegant solution.

Comment: @Stephan You accepted it - but did it resolve the issue (or at least *help* to resolve it)? Otherwise, maybe a dedicated question about something like "Assigning priority to tasks in single threaded ScheduledExecutorService" or so might attract some attention and bring some more help (particularly when you mention the constraint that it *must* be single-threaded already in the question)

Comment: I accepted the answer because it helped me to locate the issue. My workaround is a rescheduling task that measures the time, cancels scheduled tasks and reschedules them with a longer time interval.

Comment: That sounds like a hassle. I think that some concept of priorities in a ScheduledExecutorService would be nice, though. But as I mentioned, it seems that it could be difficult to implement it based on the existing implementations (in fact, I think that implementing this "from scratch", in form of an own "PriorityScheduledExecutorService" might be easier). However, if you found a solution that is satisfactory, then it's OK for now.